# The meaning of this sentence in detail

Tags: meaning, synonyms, questions, writing, quotes

I'm watching Trevor Noah's video on YouTube.
https://youtu.be/v4amCfVbA_c

At about 7:30,
'But I think what people take for how much, for so many people, that feels like nothing, you know?'

I don't understand what this means.
Can you explain it in easy words?
And let me know what 'that' means in 'that feels like nothing'.
Thank you :)

Comment: That’s not an accurate transcription of what he says, but it’s not our purpose to do that kind of work.

Answer (score 1):

I think he was trying to say that'' so many people taking drugs in high dose (according to them ) is nothing for me . It may be the meaning of the above sentence if you compare that unknown substance to drugs .

That feels nothing here may be mean to say that effect of drug (like insomnia , hallucinations etc) feels nothing to me ..